# How to pass an object from a main form to a plugin in C#

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a windows application (C# , .Net 4.0). This windows application is plugin based. I would like to pass an object from the main application to a plugin.

Somebody care to show me an example please? .

Comment: What plugin system are you using? Can you post some code to show what you've already got (maybe an example of how a plugin works?) Thanks.

Comment: my code is based on this  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28949/A-Flexible-Plugin-System

Answer (score 1, accepted):

funny you should ask this, i'm working on something like this right now.

In the Interface that you are defining for the Plugins, provide a method/property that is the Interface from your application that the plugin can use.

Then inside your application implement that interface.

Now on your plugin call your Method passing in that Class that.

Now inside the plugin it will be able to utilise the methods and properties you have designed in the interface.

```
interface IPlugin
{
    void CanBeCalledByTheApplication(IAppObject main);
}


interface IAppObject
{
    void Alert(string msg);
}
```

Now in your implementation of the plugin you can just go

```
 main.Alert("this is my message");
```

And in your application you'd go

```
(IPlugin)myPlugin.CanBeCalledByTheApplication(someObject);
```

This is obviously not a complete example, but you should be able to get the idea.

Comment: Paul .. thanks for taking time out for me. I was wondering if it would be a nice idea to put my concrete class in the same assembly as the Interface. that way its available to the main app as well as the plugin. is that a good idea ?

Comment: put your interface in a separate assembly, this way you can (potentially) distribute your plugin interface to other developers without them requiring the latest version of the applicaiton they are going to be hosted within. You can also then test the plugins by proving an alternate testing engine/mocks etc.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. it was late last night. I still had something in my mind and wanted to clear it out.. What I have might be a very bad idea , but still i would like to know why ts a bad idea . 

The idea that I has was , put my concrete class and the interface (that the users will implement to build the plugin) in a separate assembly and distribute it. This concrete class is just a set of few properties and has an overriden ToString() method. what I was also wondering is to add this concrete class as a linked file in vs2010.
Is this a good idea? or a very bad one. Please let me know..

Comment: App References Interfaces .
Plugins Refences Interfaces dll having the 2 parts mixed together will bite you.
BTW. have you thought about maybe accepting an answer or upvote?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I have done both of them.. upvoted as well as marked it as an answer. I have started using MEF, however .. :)